# laravel 5.5 migrations not creating migration records

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-artisan, migrate

when I run `php artisan migrate` I get two tables `users` and `migrations`. but when I run the same command again to add new table. I get the following error,

```
`PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already excists: 1050 
 Table 'users' already exists")`
```

when I checked the `migrations` table it is empty. I have not manually deleted anything from the database or even deleted any migration files in laravel.

what is causing this, and how to solve it.

Comment: thanks it works now I changed the sizes of the string fields and ran `php artisan migrate:fresh`  now it created without error and populated migrations table too

Comment: Answer your own question and close it @Naveed Sheriffdeen